# Scroll area in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a layout with this style

[image]
[image]

in this design all of arrow sliding 
in red square i have list view 
in orange square i have slider

## How can I scroll my layout show with red arrow

## Best xml design for this

same as this
 or hide slider when scroll list view ?

[image]

Comment: in your list adapter implementation, you override getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType and in getView first item pass the slider and other pass the other view for those item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            listView1.scrollBy(0, 1);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll the entire screen you can put a `ScrollView` around everything, which will include both the `Slider` and the `ListView` sections